# Matching value from one date to the same date in another table for Brokerage

Tags: microsoft-excel

My brain just can't get around this. Will PayPal $20 if someone can solve this.

I have a list of dates with values attached to them (365 days each with their own value). Now I have another list just with dates but there's 2k of them which means some dates are repeated. I've tried this with vlookup but it only works 365 times until each value has been assigned once.
I'm trying it with INDEX but I can't get it to work.

Comment: To help us better understand your issue, could you please share us with a simple sample? Then we can provide the formulas according on it.

Answer (score -1):

There's only one way your situation makes sense.

That is if you are setting a formula alongside each of the dates in the "2k list" to do a lookup in the "365 list" to get the values. Except... instead of the lookup value being the "2k list" cells, you have crossed your wires and they are actually the "365 list" range, extended quite past it. So the lookup is finding 365 values, then looking up a long list of blank values and returning blank values (since, of course, there are no values alongside the blanks).

That might not be utterly clear to you so I shall give an example. Say the "365 list" is in column A, cells A1:A365, and their associated values are alongside them in cells B1:B365. Then the "2k list" is in column D, in cells D1:D2000. Finally, your formulas are in column E, alongside them, in cells E1:E2000. All good so far.

I am saying the formula you are using is something close to the following:

```
=VLOOKUP( A1, $A$1:$A$2000, 2, FALSE)
```

and the formula is then copied down column E to fill E1:E2000.

In this case, since the column A values are being looked for, there are 365 of them that will be found and a value from column B returned. Once you get to row 366, the value to lookup becomes an empty cell, a blank. That is happily looked up, and found, and then the value to its right is returned. That value is, of course, a blank as well so it looks like nothing more is returned as you go from cell E366 to cell E2000.

Easy to fix.

Just replace the lookup value in the formula with D1 (replace A1 with D1). Now the formula is looking up dates from the "2k list" instead of looking up dates from the "365 list" and you will get all "2k" values you expect.

No other explanation (likely ones anyway) make sense as the results would differ from your reported results, so this must be it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).